# Custom Django Log Config with Default Config

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to setup my Django app and am running into problems configuring logging in settings.py file.

Django documentation and Python's logging documentation states that using:
`'disable_existing_loggers': False` will allow me to use the existing logging configuration so that I don't have to repeat myself. The default logging in this case is the DEFAULT_LOGGING dict found in `django.utils.log.py`

When I try to use existing filters in `DEFAULT_LOGGING`, `require_debug_true`, in my one of my handlers for `LOGGING_CONFIG` in settings.py, I get a KeyError when trying to run runserver.

I also get the same error when trying to use existing handlers in my logger, such as `console`. The only reason I can think of is that somehow Django is disregarding the `disable_existing_loggers` flag.

Has anyone run into this issue before? Thanks for the help.

```
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 750, in add_handlers

       logger.addHandler(self.config['handlers'][h])
     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 317, in __getitem__
       value = dict.__getitem__(self, key)
   KeyError: 'console'

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 611, in configure
       self.configure_logger(name, loggers[name])
     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 775, in configure_logger
       self.common_logger_config(logger, config, incremental)

     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 767, in common_logger_config
       self.add_handlers(logger, handlers)
     File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 752, in add_handlers
       raise ValueError('Unable to add handler %r: %s' % (h, e))
   ValueError: Unable to add handler 'console': 'console'



LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'activity': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(pathname)s <%(funcName)s>[%(lineno)s] : %(message)s',
        },
        'debug': {
            'format': '[%(levelname)s] %(pathname)s <%(funcName)s>[%(lineno)s] : %(message)s',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'debug': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/www/app/log/debug.log',
            'formatter': 'debug',
            'backupCount': 48,
            'when': 'H',
        },
        'activity': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/www/app/log/activity.log',
            'formatter': 'activity',
            'backupCount': 48,
            'when': 'H',
        },
        'error': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/www/app/log/error.log',
            'formatter': 'activity',
            'backupCount': 48,
            'when': 'H',
        },
        'syslog': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SysLogHandler',
            'formatter': 'activity',
            'facility': SysLogHandler.LOG_LOCAL2,
            'address': '/dev/log',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'app.activity': {
            'handlers': ["activity", "error", "debug"],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ["mail_admins", "error", "activity", "debug"],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django.security': {
            'handlers': ["mail_admins", "error", "activity"],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'py.warnings': {
            'handlers': ["console", "debug"],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Could you show your _logging configuration_ in settings.py?

Comment: I suppose that might be helpful... added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you need to add configuration of `console` Handler and the rest of handlers, filters and formatters (which you use) from `django.utils.log.py` to logging configuration.

`disable_existing_loggers` parameter regards only to loggers (not to handler, filter and formatter)

Comment: I think you might be right, gotta read documentation carefully. logger != log config. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to keep the default logging configuration and customize only some settings is by updating `django.utils.log.DEFAULT_LOGGING` that is used by Django to configure logging:

```
from django.utils.log import DEFAULT_LOGGING

# Enable logging to console from our modules by configuring the root logger
DEFAULT_LOGGING['loggers'][''] = {
    'handlers': ['console'],
    'level': 'INFO',
    'propagate': True
}
```

This is has to be in `settings.py` as logging will be configured immediately after settings have been imported.

Comment: Saves a lot of headache for some simple debugging purpose.